# Cannot add users to local group via powershell

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, powershell

Trying to import a large list of users for mac authentication. I can create the users but no matter what I try I cannot add them to a local group.  I continually get "an invalid directory pathname was passed" to the add function.

Here is the actual error:

```
Method invocation failed because [System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry] does not contain a method named
'op_Addition'.
At C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Import Script\Import1.ps1:12 char:2
+     $objuser = [ADSI]"WinNT://RadiusSVR/" + $_.MAC
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (op_Addition:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound

Exception calling "Add" with "1" argument(s): "An invalid directory pathname was passed



$Computername = $env:COMPUTERNAME
$objgroup = [ADSI]"WinNT://./TEST" 
$target = [ADSI]"WinNT://$Computername"

Import-Csv testlist1.csv | ForEach-Object { 
    $newuser = $target.Create("user", $_.MAC) 
    $newuser.SetPassword($_.MAC) 
    $newuser.SetInfo() 
    $newuser.FullName = ($_.NAME)
    $newuser.SetInfo()
    $newuser.psbase.InvokeSet('AccountDisabled', $false) 
    $newuser.SetInfo() 
    $objuser = [ADSI]"WinNT://./" + $_.MAC
    $objgroup.Add($objuser) 
}
```

I've tried replacing WinNT://. with WinNT://RadiusSVR but same issue, same if I try WinNT://$Computername.

Before someone asks, yes I mean to set username and password to the mac address.    The users are created just fine, but its getting them into said group that is the issue.

Comment: `$objgroup.psbase.Invoke("Add",($objuser).path)` maybe you need to specify `$objuser` also a little different. refer to: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/scriptcenter/en-US/35b8022e-7c0e-49fb-b4c7-346b83ed3fd0/powershell-oneliner-to-add-domain-user-to-a-local-group?forum=ITCG

Comment: @SimonS Still getting path errors if I try :   $de = [ADSI]"WinNT://RadiusSVR/TEST,group" 
 $de.psbase.Invoke("Add",([ADSI]"WinNT://RadiusSVR/$_.MAC").path).  I don't know what it doesn't like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally after fighting with multiple iterations of the line containing $objuser someone suggested doing it this way in another forum.  It works, effortlessly.

NO matter what other way I tried it was throwing type mismatch errors.

```
$Info = Import-CSV -Path "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Import Script\testlist1.csv"

foreach ($user in $Info)

{
#Create the user using the property from the CSV called Name
net user $user.MAC /add;

#Set the user's password to the property from the CSV called MAC
 net user $user.MAC $user.MAC

 #Actually add them to group
 net localgroup "TEST" /add $user.MAC}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
$objuser = [ADSI]"WinNT://./$($_.MAC)"
$objgroup.Add($objuser)
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you are not using New-ADUser and Add-ADGroupMember cmdlets?

Try changing this

```
[ADSI]"WinNT://./" + $_.MAC
```

to this

```
[ADSI]("WinNT://./" + $_.MAC)
```

You were casting `"WinNT://./"` to an ADSI object and then trying to add `$_.Mac`which will not work. Create the whole string and then cast it to an ADSI object.